# Trouble with 2 counting rules problems (combination rule, permutation rule, partitions rule)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I am having trouble figuring out the answer to the following counting rules problems. No matter what I try, my answer does not match the answer key from my course (and there are no solutions provided, just the final probability). I know that I have to use the combination rule (NCn) as order does not matter in these questions but I just can't seem to crack them. Any help will be appreciated!

These questions come from a document that the professor generated years ago as general practice problems for the course.

> **Q1**. Eight male and eight female Psychology 020 students are going to be assigned to samples of sizes 2, 6, and 8 to participate as subjects in different research experiments. If assignment to the samples is random, what is the probability that no more than 2 female will end up in the sample of size 6?

So N = 16, Males = 8, Females = 8

My initial logic to solve this question would be choosing the number of males and females to make up to group of 6 divided by the total number of ways to pick six people from the group of 16. For this question stating **no more than 2 females**, this would mean that there are either:

a. 6 males, 0 females
b. 5 males, 1 female
6. 4 males, 2 females

(8C6)(8C0)/(16C6) + (8C5)(8C1)/(16C6) + (8C4)(8C2)/(16C6) 
= .00349 + .05594 + .2447 
= **.3041**

The answer I am given by the professor is a final probability of having no more than 2 females in the group of 6 is .0594.

I am not sure then what logic to follow.

> **Q2**. Twenty people (12 females and 8 males) are applying for jobs at a company that needs to fill 10 Management positions, 6 Sales positions, and 4 Secretarial positions. Eight of the 12 female applicants have a B.A. degree; 5 of the 8 male applicants have a B.A. degree; the remaining applicants have no university degree. If the company hires all 20 of the applicants but then assigns them to the 3 different job categories at random…

**a.** What is the probability that at least 5 of the Sales positions are filled by people with B.A. degrees?

**b.** In how many ways can the applicants be assigned such that equal numbers of males and females with B.A.s end up in Management positions and all the Sales positions are filled by females?

Comment: "*The answer I am giving is... $.0594$*"  Where does $.0594$ come from?  The calculations in the line before that are correct and the logic should be readily understood...

Comment: For Q2.a, just combine the male and female applicants who have BA degrees into one category.  Then follow the same logic as the first question.  Getting exactly five people with BA's and one person without can be done in $\binom{13}{5}\binom{7}{1}$ ways and so on... For Q2.b a very similar line of logic will work, but now we might need to start working with the *multivariable*-hypergeometric distribution instead of the usual hypergeometric distribution.  The word might sound scary, but it just means that we pay attention to more than just two categories now, the calculations are otherwise same

Comment: @JMoravitz this was a typo on part, I apologize. .0594 is the answer given by the professor.

Comment: @user376343 No.  It is completely irrelevant how the remaining women are distributed among the remaining groups.  You could account for that in your calculation, sure, but then your denominator will need to reflect that as well and it will just cancel out.  The answer arrived at by the OP is the correct answer, $.0594$ is an incorrect answer for how the problem is currently written and phrased.

Comment: It is possible that somehow you or your professor had mixed the phrases "No more than $2$" which allows $2$ as a possibility with "Not $2$ or more" which does not allow $2$ as a possibility.  That would explain the value of $.0594$ as it would be $\dfrac{\binom{8}{0}\binom{8}{6}+\binom{8}{1}\binom{8}{5}}{\binom{16}{6}}$

Comment: @JMoravitz that is my thinking yes. I will bring it up with them. Thank you so much for your help and detailed answers!